# Determining from which View/UserControl a Command was called

Tags: c#, mvvm

Is there any definitive way of determining from which View (UserControl) a command was called?

For instance, if I have two Views, each tied to the same ViewModel, how might I determine from which View a particular command was called? Having a separate command for each View would not make a difference in this scenario, as it is an external service which ought to be notified of the particular active View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you call the command from a usercontrol. So if you call the method someMethod for example then require that method to take a UserControl object as a parameter. In other words you should have somethin like:

```
  Public void someMethod(UserControl u, other params...){

    If( u is SomeUsercontrol){
      \\do somethin
      } else if....

  }
```

And on your user conrtoll call that method as:

```
      someMethod(this, .....) \\ the this keyword will send a UserControl object if you call that method within a UserControl class. In other words it will pass itself as a parameter
```

Comment: Hm, that's a great idea. I hadn't thought about passing the UserControl through the CommandParameter. I'm not sure if this breaks MVVM convention (or what side effects if could have) but it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: I would pass a token (a string of some sort) into the command parameter if there is some differences based on where the command was invoked.